# Python: read from stdin with "for _ in sys.stdin" requires two Ctrl+Ds to exit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, io

This question is specific to Python 2.7. I'm using Linux. The question is about the following 3-line python program.

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   print line
```

Question 1: When I run the program and type my input, why doesn't the program print anything when I press enter? It only prints after I press Ctrl+D.

Question 2: After I press Ctrl+D, why doesn't the program exit? Pressing Ctrl+D once prints all the stuff I typed so far (as mentioned in Question 1). I have to press Ctrl+D again to exit. I thought Ctrl+D was supposed to mark the end of file of sys.stdin? But apparently no: I can type a bunch of things, press Ctrl+D to print, type a bunch of things again, press Ctrl+D again, and so on.

Question 2 (extra): When I redirect a file into the program, as opposed to typing directly into the terminal, the program does terminate properly---that is, I don't need to "end the file twice" by pressing Ctrl+D twice. How come typing into the terminal is different?

Question 3: How come this program *does* work as expected in Python 3? (i.e. it echoes back what I typed in every time I press enter) What changed?

I anticipate that a good answer to this question would explain what is the iterator returned by sys.stdin in a for loop, and exactly what the iterator and the Python interpreter are doing. Other websites seem to vaguely point out that "`for line in sys.stdin`" reads the whole file before executing the for loop, but it doesn't explain why and how that works, why it *doesn't* work that way in Python 3, and why I need to press Ctrl+D twice on the terminal.